# Mailcow - set-up Traefik docker-compose.override.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, traefik, mailcow

I am posting a link to my problem in the community forum where everything is described.

[Mailcow FORUM - My personal problem](https://community.mailcow.email/d/2337-set-up-traefik-docker-composeoverrideyml)

I simply don't know where I'm going wrong and I hope someone can help me out.

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
    nginx-mailcow:
      networks:
        # Add Traefik's network
        - proxy
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        # Creates a router called "moo" for the container, and sets up a rule to link the container to certain rule,
        #   in this case, a Host rule with our MAILCOW_HOSTNAME var.
        - traefik.http.routers.moo.rule=Host(`${MAILCOW_HOSTNAME}`)
        # Enables tls over the router we created before.
        - traefik.http.routers.moo.tls=true
        # Specifies which kind of cert resolver we'll use, in this case le (Lets Encrypt).
        - traefik.http.routers.moo.tls.certresolver=le
        # Creates a service called "moo" for the container, and specifies which internal port of the container
        #   should traefik route the incoming data to.
        - traefik.http.services.moo.loadbalancer.server.port=${HTTP_PORT}
        # Specifies which entrypoint (external port) should traefik listen to, for this container.
        #   websecure being port 443, check the traefik.toml file liked above.
        - traefik.http.routers.moo.entrypoints=websecure
        # Make sure traefik uses the web network, not the mailcowdockerized_mailcow-network
        - traefik.docker.network=proxy

    certdumper:
        image: humenius/traefik-certs-dumper
    command: --restart-containers ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-postfix-mailcow-1,${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-nginx-mailcow-1,${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-dovecot-mailcow-1
        network_mode: none
        volumes:
          # Mount the volume which contains Traefik's `acme.json' file
          #   Configure the external name in the volume definition
          - /home/archmatt/traefik/data/acme.json:/traefik:ro
          # Mount mailcow's SSL folder
          - ./data/assets/ssl/:/output:rw
          # Mount docker socket to restart containers
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        restart: always
        environment:
          # only change this, if you're using another domain for mailcow's web frontend compared to the standard config
          - DOMAIN=${MAILCOW_HOSTNAME}

networks:
  web:
    external: true
    # Name of the external network
    name: proxy

volumes:
  acme:
    external: true
    # Name of the external docker volume which contains Traefik's `acme.json' file
    name: proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

This link help me out ! :D i didn't find it before but yes ! it WORKS ! but with little edit.

[COMMUNITY POWER LETS GO STACKOVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303360/mailcow-setup-behind-traefik-proxy-causes-https-certificate-error)

but my code looks like this right now:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  nginx-mailcow:
    expose:
      - "10080"
    networks:
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-mailcow.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-mailcow.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:(autodiscover|autoconfig|webmail|mail|email).+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.nginx-mailcow-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-mailcow.middlewares=nginx-mailcow-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-mailcow-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-mailcow-secure.rule=Host(`mail.example.org`)" 
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-mailcow-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-mailcow-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-mailcow-secure.service=nginx-mailcow"
      - "traefik.http.services.nginx-mailcow.loadbalancer.server.port=10080"
      - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
  certdumper:
    image: humenius/traefik-certs-dumper
    container_name: traefik_certdumper
    network_mode: none
    command: --restart-containers mailcowdockerized_postfix-mailcow_1,mailcowdockerized_dovecot-mailcow_1
    volumes:
      - /home/archmatt/traefik/data:/traefik:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./data/assets/ssl:/output:rw
    environment:
      - DOMAIN=example.org
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

but for next step i will edit labels: with HTTPS request fully.